# Formal way to say bubble / bubbling

Tags: terminology

I know this question might seem too simplistic but I've been looking everywhere for a better than bubble but I have not found it. The most similar word would be effervescence but that's slightly different. I am "bubbling oxygen" in water and testing for oxygen dissolved but it's a formal paper and "bubbling" sounds very informal

Comment: I think "bubbling" is already formal enough. Other terms are more specific, i.e. you could use "oxygenation" or "aeration".

Comment: If OTOH the bubbling purpose is to eliminate or transfer volatile components, "stripping" or "purging" could be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term is used in scientific papers, so it's probably good enough:

- [Reactive Deposition of Cobalt Electrodes: II . Role of Bubbling Oxygen](https://doi.org/10.1149/1.2086225)
- [Ultrasonic cavitation erosion of Ti in 0.35% NaCl solution with bubbling oxygen and nitrogen](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ultsonch.2015.02.013)

Answer (score 4):

"[Sparging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparging_(chemistry))" is a common name given to bubbling a gas stream under the surface of a liquid, often with the purpose of saturating the liquid with the gas from the stream and/or displacing almost all other gasses or other volatiles from the liquid (e.g., solvents are often sparged with nitrogen or argon gas to reduce their oxygen content and allow oxidation-sensitive chemistry).